# NaOH or lye. Would it work to remove ice snow or water from a paved surface?

Tags: thermodynamics

Thinking of ways to clear ice using chemical reaction.

Comment: Yes, it probably will; it is terrible for the environment and the roads though.

Comment: All you are producing is a salt solution with a lower freezing point than pure water. There is no chemical reaction.

Comment: Lye is dangerously corrosive, so even if it worked, it would be a very bad choice as a deicing agent.

Comment: Hope everybody avoids skin contact with the paved surface after you've applied NaOH to it.

Comment: The grass probably wont grow back for a while, and parents may be upset that kids got caustic burns on their skin, you may or may not also get fined by authorities, but yes lye will melt ice.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on a chemical reaction, combine a little salt (on concrete, calcium chloride is better) with magnesia (the unhydrated oxide, not the hydroxide).  The salt melts the ice and then the magnesia, a basic anhydride, reacts with the water.  Then the salt is free to melt more water, it's acting as a catalyst while the magnesia is the actual reagent.  The product of this reaction is precipitated instead of destroying the concrete/asphalt/grass, but that also means you're left with a mess.

Or just use salt alone and rely on the usual freezing point lowering.  :-)

Comment: Use CaCl2 instead of NaCl on concrete.